# jwysiwyg jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-editor, wysiwyg, jwysiwyg

Does someone knows how to make jwysiwyg editor in fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 1):

here is an example of one:

[fullscreen wysiwyg editor](http://cutesoft.net/example/FullScreen.aspx)
or this one: [editor #2](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

Comment: eheh i know about other examples but i would like someone can tells me how to extend jwysiwyg plugin to make it fullscreen could be wonderfull for me!

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for that: https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg/blob/master/plugins/wysiwyg.fullscreen.js

You can see a running example here: http://akzhan.github.com/jwysiwyg/help/examples/11-plugins.html

You should put a little snippet of code in order to have it working:

```
fullscreen : {
                visible: true,
                exec: function () {
                    if ($.wysiwyg.fullscreen) {
                        $.wysiwyg.fullscreen.init(this);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Regards.